# Перевернуть дату

Tags: java

Как можно перевернуть дату к примеру у меня дата 2020-02-12 а мне необходимо 02-12-2020 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вообще не знаю java, но вроде что-то делает :)

```java
String Str = new String("2020-02-12");
String[] Arr = Str.split("-");
Str = String.join("-", Arr[1], Arr[2], Arr[0]);
System.out.println(Str);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(yourDateLine);
```

Или если нужно из Date в строку, то

```
String normalDate = formatter.format(date);
```